# Magento CE 1.5 creating a new var directory

Tags: magento-1

In a Magento CE 1.5 installation Magento sometimes creates new var directories (var1, var2).
As far as I can see Magento continues to work fine and nothing is wrong with the old directories but it'd like to know what causes this.

Answer (score 1):

**Magento doesn't create incremental `var` directories.**

Its more likely your developer doing it to get round having to empty the cache, remove indexing locks etc.

Check your FTP or `bash` history and you'll probably find a `mv var{,1}` in there somewhere :)

Comment: Thanks Sonassi, I've already checked the log and that's not the case unfortunatelly

Comment: Mystery solved, apparently we use a custom extension that changes the var extension when it's not writable for some reason. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sounds like a dangerous extension... :)

Comment: @SanderMangel you could always add this as an answer or close the question if you do not think it will benefit anyone.